# XMLHttpRequest.open() throws NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I want to open a local XML-file with Javascript to create out of the XML content a table on my HTML page. Therefore I have written the following javascript code to open the XML-file if a specific tag gets clicked.

```
function BuildTemplate(path) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {//Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {//Code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", path, false); // -> NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // ... generate text [table] out of XML content
    return text;
```

The path passed to the function looks like the following:

```
D://Here//Is//My//Example//Folder//ContentTable.xml
```

The Error has been thrown on Firefox but it's not working on Chrome and IE11 too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it may be a security issue, so modern browsers may have not support to reach local files.

But you can try adding `file:///` before path:

At first replace `//` to `/` in `path`:

```
path = path.replace(new RegExp('//', 'g'), '/'); //replace all occurances
```

This will change `D://Here//Is//My//Example//Folder//ContentTable.xml` into `D:/Here/Is/My/Example/Folder/ContentTable.xml`

Then prepand `file:///`:

```
path = 'file:///' + path;
```

Comment: I have tried it and now i get the following error message: `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied`

Comment: @Lehtim Sorry I had miscounted the `/` chars. I've updated the post. If it doesn't still work, it is a security preventing.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I would not have found that error because I thought // is interpreted the same like /.

Comment: @Lehtim i had the same idea at first, too:) I am glad it worked.

Comment: its working very well for Firefox but not for Chrome. Chrome does not support the protocol scheme **file** just **http**, **data**, **chrome**, **chrome-extension**, and **https**. My question would be how to change the protocol scheme. Is it possible?